# How to access JSON element from jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to target a specific element in my JSON file:

```
{
  "taskMeta": "Some meta info",
  "tasksLib": [
    {
     "task001":
         {
            "id":"1",
            "createDate":"01.02.17",
            "dueDate":"02.03.17",
            "author":"Author name",
            "tag":"Things",
            "description":"Here's a description of the todo",
            "priority":"1",
            "color":"danger",
            "title":"btn-danger",
            "content":"Here's the notes content"
         },
     "task002":
         {
            "id":"2",
            "createDate":"02.02.17",
            "dueDate":"05.03.17",
            "author":"Author name",
            "tag":"Other things",
            "description":"Here's another description of the todo",
            "priority":"0",
            "color":"info",
            "title":"Foo",
            "content":"Here's some amazing content"
         }

     }
  ]
}
```

Then it gets loaded in this js file:

```
$.ajax({
     type:     'GET',
     url:      'includes/tasks.json',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(task) {

        $.each(task, function(i, task){
           console.log(
              task.taskLib[0].id
           );
...
```

This gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: be wary: you have defined `task` twice:

success: function(**task**) {
        $.each(**task**, function(i, **task**){

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have first to parse your JSON:

```
var tasksData = JSON.parse(task);
```

Then you can loop through your tasks as below:

```
$.each(tasksData.tasksLib, function(i, task){
    console.log(task.id);
}
```

Comment: that `$.each(task, function(i, task)` triggered me^^

Comment: @xDreamCoding You are correct. I did the corresponding correction. Thanks

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean to confuse you. I ment his code with the variablenames he choose, like double use of  `task`. I think it's wrong now  still, change: `task.taskLib[0].id` to `task.id`

Comment: Not a problem at all dude ! Yeap there are a couple of misnamings. I think now it's fixed. Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

1. It's `tasksLib`, not `taskLib`
2. You should use `Object.keys()` method:

   ```
   var keys=Object.keys(task.tasksLib[0]);
   console.log(task.tasksLib[0][keys[0]].id)
   ```

```js
var task={
"taskMeta": "Some meta info",
"tasksLib": [
    {
     "task001":
         {
            "id":"1",
            "createDate":"01.02.17",
            "dueDate":"02.03.17",
            "author":"Author name",
            "tag":"Things",
            "description":"Here's a description of the todo",
            "priority":"1",
            "color":"danger",
            "title":"btn-danger",
            "content":"Here's the notes content"
         },
     "task002":
         {
            "id":"2",
            "createDate":"02.02.17",
            "dueDate":"05.03.17",
            "author":"Author name",
            "tag":"Other things",
            "description":"Here's another description of the todo",
            "priority":"0",
            "color":"info",
            "title":"Foo",
            "content":"Here's some amazing content"
         }

     }
]
}
var keys=Object.keys(task.tasksLib[0]);
keys.forEach(function(item){
   console.log(task.tasksLib[0][item].id)
});
```